# Under Ubuntu, how do I set a static IP for firewire?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, firewire

I am using Ubuntu 10.10 on my laptop, which connects to our network wirelessly. Since it sits on my desk next to my desktop, I have a private network between the two using a firewire cable, because `synergy` and file copies are much more plesant over firewire than wifi.

I want to set a static IP for the `firewire` device on boot so I don't have to keep using `ifconfig` each time. However the device doesn't appear in Gnome's NetworkManager. How can I set a static IP for the firewire device? Terminal commands are fine, as long as NetworkManager won't blow the config away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Debian and Ubuntu, the place to configure networking without Network Manager is [`/etc/network/interfaces`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man5/interfaces.5.html). Something like this should work (you may need to change the interface number):

```
auto eth2
iface eth2 inet static
    address 10.10.6.1
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 10.10.6.255
    pre-up modprobe eth1394
```

Run `ifup eth2` and `ifup eth2` to bring the interface up or down. The `auto` statement causes the interface to be brought up as part of the boot process. Network Manager won't touch an interface mentioned in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

[Zeroconf](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToZeroconf) is often nice for Firewire links: if you run it at both ends, it automatically negociates addresses and routing. However it's no help if you want a more managed network (e.g. to give your laptop a name, bring it inside a casual firewall, …).

Comment: Awesome, thanks! On my system, it was actually `firewire0`, not `eth2`, but I knew what it should be.