# Suspending my laptop breaks ethernet over firewire, are there commands which can fix it?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, suspend, firewire

As mentioned [in this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5372/under-ubuntu-how-do-i-set-a-static-ip-for-firewire) I am using a firewire cable to provide a private network between my laptop and my desktop, because it makes using the screen sharing program `synergy` much nicer than using WIFI.

However when I leave my office for the day and I suspend my laptop, when I return the next day, the desktop and the laptop cannot communicate over firewire anymore. The `firewire0` device still has an IP address. but when I try and ping the desktop I get `no route to host`

I'm using kernel `2.6.35-24-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP x86_64` on Ubuntu 10.10.

Is there some way I can remedy this without a reboot? Like, removing some kernel modules and re-inserting them?

**EDIT:** Here's what I have tried so far and the results:

```
root@token:~# dmesg|tail -n 1
[592525.204024] firewire_core: phy config: card 0, new root=ffc1, gap_count=5

root@token:~# modprobe -r firewire_net firewire_ohci firewire_core
root@token:~# modprobe -v firewire_ohci
insmod /lib/modules/2.6.35-24-generic/kernel/lib/crc-itu-t.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/2.6.35-24-generic/kernel/drivers/firewire/firewire-core.ko 
insmod /lib/modules/2.6.35-24-generic/kernel/drivers/firewire/firewire-ohci.ko 

root@token:~# dmesg|tail
[592525.204024] firewire_core: phy config: card 0, new root=ffc1, gap_count=5
[592563.410868] firewire_ohci: Removed fw-ohci device.
[592579.160086] firewire_ohci: Added fw-ohci device 0000:02:00.0, OHCI v1.10, 4 IR + 8 IT contexts, quirks 0x2
[592579.160137] firewire_ohci: isochronous cycle inconsistent
[592579.660294] firewire_core: created device fw0: GUID 0000000000000000, S400
[592579.663805] firewire_core: created device fw1: GUID 0017f2fffe89bce6, S400
[592579.663813] firewire_core: phy config: card 0, new root=ffc1, gap_count=5
[592579.700720] firewire_core: phy config: card 0, new root=ffc1, gap_count=5
[592579.700842] firewire_core: refreshed device fw0
[592579.702603] firewire_net: firewire0: IPv4 over FireWire on device 0000000000000000

root@token:~# ping stan.firewire
PING stan.firewire (192.168.100.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From token.local (192.168.100.3) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From token.local (192.168.100.3) icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From token.local (192.168.100.3) icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

**EDIT 2:** I also tried removing the modules prior to suspending, and re-inserting after resuming. This did not work either :-(

**EDIT 3:** If I unplug and replug the firewire cable after resuming from suspend, I see the message:

```
firewire_core: BM lock failed, making local node (ffc0) root
```

I don't see this message when I unplug/replug before suspend...

Comment: I have crossposted this on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/26351/suspending-my-laptop-breaks-ethernet-over-firewire-are-there-commands-which-can) because I really would like a solution!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `modprobe`?

Running `dmesg | grep firewire`, I get:

```
[    1.192574] firewire_ohci 0000:0a:04.0: PCI INT A -> GSI 20 (level, low) -> IRQ 20
[    1.192585] firewire_ohci 0000:0a:04.0: setting latency timer to 64
...
```

This says that the name of the module is **firewire_ohci**.

So I run ([as root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3063/how-do-i-run-a-command-as-the-system-administrator-root)) `modprobe -vr firewire_ohci && modprobe -v firewire_ohci`. There removes and inserts the modules, respectively.

Comment: According to the verbose output and the output of `dmesg`, that looks like it should work -- see my edited answer -- but, sadly, it doesn't... ideas on where I could go from here?

Answer (score 2):

I think that ARP-table just becomes empty.
Try this:

```
arping -c 1 -I firewire0 remote_ip
```

Comment: While this sounded promising, sadly all I get is `Sent 1 probes (1 broadcast(s))` / `Received 0 response(s)` :-(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the physical cable. it should alert the stack that the connection needs to be rebuilt.

Disabling the firewire connection and re-enabling it may work as well. You could add a script that does that automagically on resume.

DC

Comment: That's a good thought, sadly I tried that and it didn't resolve the situation...