# How can I network these two computers using eth1394/firewire-net, automagically?

Tags: networking

I have two partly-dead laptops. The first will not run X, and the second has some sort of problem with the monitor. I am not interested in repairing either of them, but since they both have firewire ports, I'd like to use some program to be able to transfer files from the second laptop (dead monitor) onto the first laptop (no X server). Ideally, I'd like to be able to browse the filesystems on the dead-screen laptop, *from the other laptop*, and have total control over it.

I need some help, though. At first, I couldn't seem to find much information about how to network them. But then I found that it was simply,

```
modprobe firewire-net
ip address add dev firewire0 <ip address>
ifconfig firewire0 up
```

which is nice. But I've never done any networking, so even though dmesg notes an IPv4 connection, I still can't transfer any files. For instance, I assigned the IP 10.10.10.11 to the first computer and 10.10.10.10 to the second, and when I type

```
ping -c 2 10.10.10.11
```

from the second, or

```
ping -c 10.10.10.10
```

from the first, I get the message:

```
connect: Network is unreachable.
```

But how can I make the module load at boot time, and the interface configure automatically, since the screen almost always dies on the second after about 10 minutes of use? Presumably, I need to add stuff to /etc/network/interfaces, right? And once the interface is connected, what program can I use to grab files on the dead-screen laptop?

Comment: 1: what the output of `route -n` prints? 2: what distro are you using (relate to  the networking on reboot setting) which basically you need to add `ONBOOT=yes` in the relevant interface file (on redhat based systems).

Comment: Don't use `ifconfig`, or any other old tools from `net-tools`… and why use both `ip` and `ifconfig`. The former can do everything! `s/ifconfig/ip link set dev/`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a similar question already answered, though it's for a static 1394 device

Have you read [Under Ubuntu, how do I set a static IP for firewire?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5372/under-ubuntu-how-do-i-set-a-static-ip-for-firewire)